# General Usage has a slow Framerate

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit, amd-graphics, framerate

this is especially noticeable in code editors, where there is more than usual re-drawing going on. But lag also happens in web browsers when navigating and scrolling. Scrolling seems to lag, too. so.. not sure what's going on there.

I don't even know where to start.

Here is some system info:

```
Graphics Card(s): 
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus XT [Radeon HD 8870M / R9 M270X/M370X] (rev 83)

Connected Monitors: 
[    20.895] (II) RADEON(0): Output eDP connected
[    20.895] (II) RADEON(0): Output DisplayPort-1 connected

Current Video Driver: 
drm_kms_helper        151552  2 amdgpu,radeon
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   352256  7 amdgpu,radeon,ttm,drm_kms_helper

Video Output Locations: 
find: ‘/dev/vboxusb’: Permission denied
/dev/fb0
/dev/dri/card0
/dev/dri/renderD128

Grub boot command: 
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-27-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=318b46d7-0efc-4fed-a30f-0c7406e13352 ro quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor vt.handoff=7

modprobe.d drivers: 
/etc/modprobe.d/
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-firewire.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-oss.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/qemu-system-x86.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-modem.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-watchdog.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/vmwgfx-fbdev.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf

Do we have a xorg.conf file?
ls: cannot access '/etc/X11/xorg.conf': No such file or directory

glxinfo: 
/home/me/scripts/system-utils/graphics-info: line 25: glxinfo: command not found

Drivers loaded by Xorg: 
[    20.463] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    20.477] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[    20.479] (II) LoadModule: "radeon"
[    20.482] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    20.484] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    20.485] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    20.501] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    20.504] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    20.507] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    20.507] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[    20.895] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    21.628] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[    21.791] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
```

The above output is from:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "\n\e[01;33mGraphics Card(s): \e[00m";
lspci | grep VGA;

echo -e "\n\e[01;33mConnected Monitors: \e[00m";
egrep -i " connected|card detect|primary dev" /var/log/Xorg.0.log;

echo -e "\n\e[01;33mCurrent Video Driver: \e[00m";
lsmod | grep "kms\|drm";

echo -e "\n\e[01;33mVideo Output Locations: \e[00m";
find /dev -group video;

echo -e "\n\e[01;33mGrub boot command: \e[00m";
cat /proc/cmdline;

echo -e "\n\e[01;33mmodprobe.d drivers: \e[00m";
find /etc/modprobe.d/;

echo -e "\n\e[01;33mDo we have a xorg.conf file?\e[00m";
ls /etc/X11/xorg.conf;

echo -e "\n\e[01;33mglxinfo: \e[00m";
glxinfo | grep -i "vendor\|rendering";

echo -e "\n\e[01;33mDrivers loaded by Xorg: \e[00m";
grep LoadModule /var/log/Xorg.0.log;
```

Also:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

$ uname -a
Linux macbuntu 4.10.0-27-generic #30~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 29 16:07:46 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output from sudo dmidecode:

http://text-share.com/view/00d1973f

any help would be super appreciated :-)

Update

output from lspci -v (but just the snippet for VGA)

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus XT [Radeon HD 8870M / R9 M270X/M370X] (rev 83) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Radeon R9 M370X Mac Edition
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 37
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at b0c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at b0c40000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
```

Comment: Have you installed the `amdgpu-pro` driver?

Comment: how would I know if I have?

Comment: You would remember if you had

Comment: If you can't remember (seemed an odd answer) check the output of 'lspci -v'. Look for your VGA card, at the end of the section it will indicate what driver is being used. Also, I thought the Radeon drivers were not yet ported over to 16.04 ?

Comment: @AndroidDev I _think_ I may have given that a shot when I totally destroyed  my x11 setup, and decided to just reinstall. So.. I don't _think_ I installed it again on the newer install.

Comment: @hatterman added my `lspci -v` output to my question -- it says I'm using radeon / amdgpu